# Does Someone Have a Recipe to Configure IPSEC/LT2P-PSK VPN for the Pi?

Tags: software-installation

I am wondering if someone has a recipe to configure IPSEC/LT2P-PSK VPN for the Pi. I am interested in being able to connect to it with an iDevice, and an Android phone.

Answer (score 3):

I dont have a recipe for installing a IPSEC / L2TP VPN; I tried to install it and after a couple of hours gave up in frustration and opted for a PPTP VPN.

PPTP is much easy to manage and install, although please take note its not as secure as IPSEC / L2TP, but it will support connections from iOS and Android devices unlike OpenVPN.

Depending on why you need a VPN, the increased risk associated to using PPTP over IPSEC/L2TP might be acceptable, if it is you will find a recipe for installing PPTP here http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/08/raspberry-pi-use-as-vpn-server.html

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit (just the highlights) on how the level of security if lower with PPTP VPN, compared to OpenVPN ?

Comment: It uses an older cipher but is still pretty difficult to crack. Keep in mind that VPN can run pretty slow on the Pi because of allot of encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this exactly is what your looking for but this tut may help you:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21429092/OpenVpn%20server%20Raspberry%20Pi.pdf

Comment: Can you provide a summary?

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN now has Windows/Mac/Android/iOS clients. Here is a pretty good write up on OpenVPN for Raspberry Pi.
http://sandeepmore.com/blog/2012/08/21/openvpn-for-raspberrypi-static-key/

A quick and easy write up for PPTP VPN on Raspberry Pi. 
http://www.sigwo.com/sshvpn-setup-guides-for-raspberry-pi/